# Even spacing between successive textblocks (or equivalent)

Tags: positioning, posters

I am writing a poster in LaTeX (`\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}`)
Each block of the poster is created with textblock, like:

```
%MOTIVATION
\begin{textblock}{16.4}(.3,1.8)
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mybox] (box){%
      \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
         ---Some Text----
      \end{minipage}
    };
    \node[fancytitle, right=30pt,rounded corners=10pt] at (box.north
west) {\Huge{Introduction}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{textblock}
```

The problem is that `textblock` takes an absolute position; so, for each textblock, I have to place the new block manually; it is impossible to place
the blocks with regular spacing (i.e. keep `\vgap` between two blocks
identical).
Is it possible to place the textblock with something like

```
\textblock{size}{x-coor, "\vspace{1cm} from the bottom of the last block"}
```

I don't have any commitment to `textblock`, so any other way of achieving
this will be appreciated.

I tried to get rid of `textblock` alltogether, with `\vspace` at the bottom
of each `textblock`, like

```
\vspace{1cm}

%MOTIVATION
%\begin{textblock}{16.4}(.3,1.8)
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mybox] (box){%
      \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
         ---Some Text---
      \end{minipage}
    };
    \node[fancytitle, right=30pt,rounded corners=10pt] at (box.north
west) {\Huge{Introduction}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
%\end{textblock}
```

The problem is that, as my poster has a 2-column, top-down layout, I
cannot place "blocks" in the 2nd column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might you consider the `stackengine` package to stack your poster blocks?  The "short-stacking" mechanism allows for a constant vertical gap between stacked items.  Then, you don't need to worry about absolute positioning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newlength\hgap
\hgap=2ex
\setstackgap{S}{2ex}
\begin{document}
\def\blockA{\fbox{\parbox[b]{2in}{Introduction\\\Large This is my text block}}}
\def\blockB{\rule{1.8in}{1.8in}}
\def\blockC{\fbox{\parbox[b]{2in}{Setup\\\Large This is my text block}}}
\def\blockD{\fbox{\parbox[b]{2in}{Results\\\Large This is my text block
  in which I share my results}}}
\def\blockE{\rule{.84in}{.84in}\hskip\hgap\rule{.84in}{.84in}}
\def\blockF{\fbox{\parbox[b]{2in}{Conclusions\\\Large This is my text block
  in which I share my conclusions}\strut}}

\centering
\Huge Framistats of the 20th Century\\
\footnotesize Prof. Z. Courantloop\\
\Shortstack{\blockA\\ \blockB\\ \blockC}
\hskip \hgap
\Shortstack{\blockD \\ \\ \blockE \\ \\ \blockF}

\end{document}
```

[image]