# which poster package should be used?

Tags: posters

A rather strange requirement was mailed to me. The dimension of

> 115 cm × 145 cm

should be applied for a poster.
According to [various defined paper sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size), that's not a standard as far as I saw.
Anyway, can you recommend any packages concerning this circumstance?

Comment: You could use the `geometry` package to set your page size, develop the layout in normal font size, and then use a `\scalebox` (of the `graphicx` package) on that layout to scale the layout to the proper size.  As far as poster layout, I'm sure there are packages.  If none suit, you can build your own like here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122062/placing-textblock-or-equivalent-in-same-seperation/122073#122073

Comment: Have a look at http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=2272. It shows how to create a rollup-display with LaTeX. The general mechanism is surely applicable in your case as well.

Comment: pdfscreen can handle weird sizes.

Comment: Are there any news here? Did the comments above help you in figuring out a solution? Can you provide a self-answer?