# minipages: multi sized minipages that use all space on the paper and automatic scaling

Tags: minipage, geometry

I am creating a sheet with solutions to different qualifying questions. Each solution takes up a different length but I don't want to waste any white space.
[image]

I want to put other `minipages` that will butt up against the end of ever `minipage` above it. My current setup is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 0.1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent % left out of MWE but in real doc
\begin{minipage}{0.965\linewidth} 
% had to play with this value so the pages wouldnt go out of bounds
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
text
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
text
\par\bigskip
text
\par\medskip
text
\end{minipage}
}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
text
\end{minipage}
}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

1. How can I keep stacking `minipages` so they will fill the empty space?
2. Without playing around with first `minipages` `linewidth`, can I tell LaTeX that I want each `minipage` to take up `0.33` of the usable space?

A desired outcome will (not boxed to solutions scale) look like
[image]

---

**multicol suggestion produces**

From the suggestions of using 3 columns, I have more issues. From the cropped image below, the `minipage` in the second column is able to fit entirely in the first column under the first `minipage` but it is being forced into the second column, and the third `minipage` which should be in column two is running out of bounds.
[image]

---

**mdframed suggestion produces**

The frame when using `mdframed` gets chopped off by `multicol`, the top margin in the first column isn't respected, and the second framed environment wont stack under the first again even though there is space
[image]

Comment: Why not use 3 columns?

Comment: @Sigur I want to `\fbox` each different solution, and I dont want the solutions to go on multiple columns.

Comment: If you use minipages in columns, they shouldn't break.

Comment: There will still be some `colsep`.

Comment: @Johannes_B it isn't stacking separate `minipages` that will fit entirely in one column as well.

Comment: I'm not sure but shouldn't you use `\noindent` before the first `minipage`?

Comment: Can you add the 3col-code you are just testing to the question?

Comment: @Johannes_B I am actually just testing it on the main doc. I don't have any test code. I just added that MWE from scratch.

Comment: @Sigur I moved `\noindent` inside the `multicols` environment and the extra padding has been removed.

Comment: @Sigur the frame when using `mdframed` gets chopped off by `multicol`, the top margin in the first column isn't respected, and the second framed environment wont stack under the first again even though there is space.

Comment: Do you want only one box on each of the 3 columns? Or do you want to stack a lot of boxes and change the column when necessary automatically, allowing box breaking?

Comment: @Sigur I want to stack a bunch of boxes. Each previous qualifying question will get its own box. For box breaking, it depends. I would have to see the results compared to the question being framed.

Comment: you have a word space either side of the minipage within each box is that intended? it makes the with of the box .3\linewidth+.666666em+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule which makes calculation (eg whether three fit in a line) harder than it might be, especially as you have a word-space between each box as well.

Comment: This answer using `stackengine` stacks may be adapted, I think: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122062/even-spacing-between-successive-textblocks-or-equivalent/122073#122073.  Just set the `\hgap` to 0pt and `\setstackgap{S}{0pt}`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes something must be wrong. You are suggesting using stackengine for _stacking boxes_ ? :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 'Tis the Season!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 0.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\lineskip{0pt}
\raggedcolumns
\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{3}
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
text
\end{minipage}}


\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
text
\par\bigskip
text
\par\medskip
text
\end{minipage}}

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
text
\end{minipage}}

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
text
\end{minipage}}


\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
text
\par\bigskip
text
\par\medskip
text
\end{minipage}}

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
text\\text2\\text3\\text4
\end{minipage}}

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
text
\end{minipage}}


\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
text
\end{minipage}}


\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
text
\par\bigskip
text
\par\medskip
text
\end{minipage}}


\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
text\\text2
\end{minipage}}

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
text
\end{minipage}}


\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain `\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax` so I have a better understanding of this line?

Comment: @dustin you have a minipage in an fbox so it has a rule of width \fboxrule either side with \fboxsep padding between the rule and the minipage, and you want the outer dimension to be `\linewidth` so the width of the minipage needs to be that much less than `\linewidth`. (it is not taking account of that and missing `%` at end of line) that you were having to guess random fractions of the width in the original.

Comment: My fboxes are overlapping. I dont know why since I have added all the setlengths as well.

Comment: @dustin If you have overlapping boxes you have introduced negative space somewhere, or specified boxes wider than the column width if you mean one column overlaps the other. Impossible to say unless you provide an example. possibly a new question?

Comment: Changing columnsep to 3pt did the trick.

Comment: if your boxes were 3pt wider than \linewidth sounds like you have a `%` missing from end of line somewhere. @dustin

Answer (score 0):

If you accept 2 columns, the code below should work, using `mdframed`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=1pt,leftmargin=0pt,rightmargin=0pt]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{mdframed}
\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=1pt,leftmargin=0pt,rightmargin=0pt]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

ps. it is necessary to take care of the vertical spaces between two boxes. Maybe some negative space.