# minipage intelligent management

Tags: minipage

Is it possible to let LaTeX manage `minipage` placement similar to how LaTeX manages figures and tables to be placed? This question comes from my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214569/minipages-multi-sized-minipages-that-use-all-space-on-the-paper-and-automatic-s).

I could move the `minipages` around manual for the best use of space but this becomes a hassle as the number of `minipages` increases. If possible, it would convenient for LaTeX to handle this task.

Can this be done?

---

**Note:**

I want management like a `float` environment but not a float. As I stated in the linked post, I want to place `minipages` that butt up against each other across three columns. I dont want wasted white space (like a float would induce). I do want the the `minipages` to be able to rearrange themselves for the **best** use of the page without me going in and placing them higher or lower in the document.

Comment: The note is a bit strange as the only reason latex moves floats is to avoid having excess white space so I'm not sure what you mean by "wasted white space (like a float would induce)" You have given no information about what this "intelligent" management is supposed to do. If the boxes can not be re-ordered and there is no space between them then essentially there is nothing you can do other than typeset them one after another as in my answer to your last question. If you are allowed to re-order the boxes then the problem has _lots_ more possibilities (and it's a lot harder to code in tex)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This puts each box at the end of the first column in which it fits:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 0.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\lineskip{0pt}
\raggedcolumns
\newcount\myboxes

\newenvironment{mbxs}{\par}{%
\myboxes=10000
\noindent
\loop
\box\myboxes\penalty0\hskip0pt plus .7\textwidth
\advance\myboxes 1
\ifvoid\myboxes
\else
\repeat
\par}

%\tracingall

\newcommand\mbx[1]{%
\setbox0\hbox{\fbox{%
  \parbox{\dimexpr.3333333\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{#1}}}%
\myboxes=10000
\loop
\ifdim\dimexpr\ht\myboxes+\dp\myboxes+\ht0+\dp0\relax>.95\textheight
\advance\myboxes1
\repeat
\ifvoid\myboxes
\setbox\myboxes\vtop{\kern0pt}%
\fi
\setbox\myboxes\vtop{\unvbox\myboxes\nointerlineskip\box0}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mbxs}
\mbx{www\\one\\two}
\mbx{\begin{itemize}\item aaaa \item bbbb \item ccc\end{itemize}}
\mbx{\def\a{One two three four. }\a xx \a\a yy yy yy \a\a\a\a}
\mbx{zzzzz\[\frac{1}{2}^{3}\]}
\mbx{zzz\\one $1=1$ and two $x^2=2$ and three $y_3=3^3$.}
\mbx{one\\two\\three $x_{x_x}$}
\mbx{\begin{itemize}\item aaaa \item bbbb \item ccc\item ddd\end{itemize}}
\mbx{\def\a{One two three four five six. }\a xx \a\a yy yy yy \a\a\a\a}
\mbx{cc\\zzzzz\[\frac{1}{2}^{3}\]zzzzz\[\frac{1111}{22222}^{3}\]}
\mbx{ONE $1=1$ AND TWO $X^2=2$ AND THREE $Y_3=3^3$.}
\mbx{one one\\four eight  $1=1$ and two $x^2=2$ and three $y_3=3^3$.}
\mbx{one\\two}
\mbx{\begin{itemize}\item aaaa \item bbbb \item ccc\end{itemize}}
\mbx{aa \def\a{One two three four. }\a xx \a\a yy yy yy \a\a\a\a}
\mbx{bb\\zzzzz\[\frac{1}{2}^{3}\]}
\mbx{one one four eight  $1=1$ and two $x^2=2$ and three $y_3=3^3$.}
\mbx{\begin{itemize}\item aaaa \item bbbb \item ccc\item ddd\end{itemize}}
\mbx{\def\a{One two three four five six. }\a xx \a\a yy yy yy \a\a\a\a}
\mbx{one\\two\\three $x_{x_x}$}
\mbx{\begin{itemize}\item aaaa \item bbbb \item ccc\item ddd\end{itemize}}
\mbx{\def\a{One two three four five six. }\a xx \a\a yy yy yy \a\a\a\a}
\mbx{\begin{itemize}\item aa\\aa \item bbbb \item ccc\item ddd\end{itemize}}
\mbx{zzzzz\[\frac{1}{2}^{3}\]zzzzz\[\frac{1111}{22222}^{3}\]}
\mbx{ONE TWO THREE  $1=1$ AND TWO $X^2=2$ AND THREE $Y_3=3^3$.}
\mbx{www\\one\\two}
\mbx{\begin{itemize}\item aaaa \item bbbb \item ccc\end{itemize}}
\mbx{\def\a{One two three four. }\a xx \a\a yy yy yy \a\a\a\a}
\mbx{zzzzz\[\frac{1}{2}^{3}\]}
\mbx{zzz\\one $1=1$ and two $x^2=2$ and three $y_3=3^3$.}
\mbx{one\\two\\three $x_{x_x}$}
\mbx{\begin{itemize}\item aaaa \item bbbb \item ccc\item ddd\end{itemize}}
\mbx{\def\a{One two three four five six. }\a xx \a\a yy yy yy \a\a\a\a}
\mbx{\begin{itemize}\item aaaa \item bbbb \item ccc\end{itemize}}
\mbx{cc\\zzzzz\[\frac{1}{2}^{3}\]zzzzz\[\frac{1111}{22222}^{3}\]}
\mbx{\begin{itemize}\item aaaa \item bbbb \item ccc\item ddd\end{itemize}}
\mbx{\def\a{One two three four five six. }\a xx \a\a yy yy yy \a\a\a\a}
\mbx{ONE $1=1$ AND TWO $X^2=2$ AND THREE $Y_3=3^3$.}
\mbx{one\\two}
\mbx{one\\two\\three $x_{x_x}$}
\mbx{aa \def\a{One two three four. }\a xx \a\a yy yy yy \a\a\a\a}
\mbx{bb\\zzzzz\[\frac{1}{2}^{3}\]}
\mbx{one one four eight  $1=1$ and two $x^2=2$ and three $y_3=3^3$.}
\mbx{zzzzz\[\frac{1}{2}^{3}\]zzzzz\[\frac{1111}{22222}^{3}\]}
\mbx{ONE TWO THREE  $1=1$ AND TWO $X^2=2$ AND THREE $Y_3=3^3$.}
\mbx{ONE TWO THREE  $1=1$ AND TWO $X^2=2$ AND THREE $Y_3=3^3$.}
\mbx{ONE TWO THREE  $1=1$ AND TWO $X^2=2$ AND THREE $Y_3=3^3$.}
\mbx{ONE TWO THREE  $1=1$ AND TWO $X^2=2$ AND THREE $Y_3=3^3$.}

\end{mbxs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A float has the white space above and below it that is what i dont want to induce or add. The boxes can be reorder like latex would do with a float. That is what is meant by intelligent mangement.

Comment: @dustin floats have skips of specified parameters added so obviously those parameters can be set to 0pt of you want them to be zero. latex never reorders figures, so I assume you don't mean "The boxes can be reorder like latex would do with a float."

Comment: I copy and pasted the code and changed the environments to mbxs and mbx but received the message bad register code (32468) `\iterate ->\ifdim \dimexpr \ht \myboxes
                                        +\dp \myboxes +\ht 0+\dp 0\relax >.9...
`

Comment: The problem occurs since I have a figure in the `\mbx` environment.

Comment: @dustin well that's simple just don't do that or at least locally within the mbxs define `figure` to do nothing. clearly floats are incompatible with this. You can't place everything in a tight array and have stuff floating to another page.

Comment: @dustin your question said to arrange minipages. You can not have a floating figure in a minipage so that would be erroneous input anyway.

Comment: Would it work the placement `H`?

Comment: @dustin no not without redefining `figure`